# Is Pinax able to be deployed on GAE?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, pinax

Is there any chance that an application developed with [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) could be deployed in Google App Engine?

As I know, Pinax is based on Django, and integrates tons of applications, it is suitable for building even a social networking site. It's extremely useful but I wonder if I can deploy it on google app engine.

Thank you,

Comment: It's hard enough to deploy pinax on a standard Ubuntu server. No way!

Comment: @Lakshman Prasad It is not very hard. I managed to do it in half an hour.

Comment: How might the upcoming [Google Cloud SQL](http://code.google.com/apis/sql/) change the situation? 

Oh: Can I use Django with Google Cloud SQL?
No, currently Google Cloud SQL is not compatible with Django. http://code.google.com/apis/sql/faq.html#django

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main issue here is that Django ORM is not compatible with GAE's datastore but [some work has already been made](http://www.clusterify.com/projects/list/dartdog/49/) to port Pinax using [app-engine-patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/). [Here is the repository](http://bitbucket.org/tbrander/pinaxcombo/).

Comment: I have not seen any update from the app-engine-patch team from July up to now, the repository you gave me is as well a little bit old. I wonder if you could tell me more about the progress of those projects?

Answer (score 1):

The key of course is JOIN support for the many to many model relationships. Since this is already being solved for 'eventual consistency' context, there should be no reason that we couldn't. I'm in the middle of moving the social demo over right now.

Answer (score 0):

"Hoang"-

It looks like there was a release on Aug 2, 2009, to include Django 1.1 (see http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/wiki/ReleaseNotes )

I know you said July, and August 2 isn't much different than July.  :)

I, too, am interested in Pinax on App Engine.   Please report your findings, if you try it!

Answer (score 0):

Pinaxcombo does it only for the blog part of Pinax. Has there been any effort to port the 'entire' Pinax onto GAE?